# Python: Vertical 1D DotPlot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to create a 1D-Dotplot with python, similar to this:

https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/public.php?service=files&t=9ead31dfc988757321c7ac391920c48a

I tried using the `plot.scatter` method from matplotlib, but it nees data for the x-axis. I tried setting all x-values to '1', but it turns out as kind of a 2d-diagram, anyway:

https://owncloud.tu-berlin.de/public.php?service=files&t=ab9f0f521f57526e871259f3a520d94a

How can I draw a real 1d-dotplot? I found nothing in the matplotlib-docs...
 I would like to use matplotlib but am also open to other suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers, Jakob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, also the 1D-Dotplot you're showing is two dimensional but only strongly limited in x direction.

I don't know whether there already exists something like that but the following code is doing what you ask for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpl

# your data
data = 3. + 0.7 * np.random.randn(N)

# a small spreading of the data in x direction
x = 0.2 * np.random.randn(data.size)

# the plotting
fig,ax = mpl.subplots(1,figsize=(0.5,5))
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('#FFD7B1')
ax.scatter(x,data,alpha=0.2,c='k')
ax.plot([-1,1],[np.mean(data),np.mean(data)],'r',linewidth=2)
ax.set_xlim((-1,1))
ax.set_ylim((1,6))
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.grid(True,axis='y')
ax.set_ylabel('Note')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your own solution is close! Just play with the aspect ratio to "squash" down the size along the x-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.randn(100)

fh, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.set_xlim(-.5, 1.5)
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)  # remove the x-axis and its ticks
ax.set_aspect(5, adjustable='box')  # adjustable='box' is important here
plt.show()
```

[image: 1D dotplot]